# Creating an optional Parameter in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, .net

How can I make a parameter in reportviewer as optional, so that if the parameter is empty or null then it is ignored and the report should not apply filter on it?

Comment: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/managing-reportviewer-parameters

Comment: show us what you have tried and provide more detail about your problem so that we can get your point easily

Comment: ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[1];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("OrderId", txtId.Text);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);

this.OrdersDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.SalesTable.OrdersData);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Comment: I have passed OrderId as report parameter at run time to filter records based on this Id. But I wants that if user does not select this Id on the form then report should ignore it and fetch all the records.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ensure that the parameter is nullable within SQL Server Report Builder. Double click on the parameter in question and select the Allow null value.

I would post an image but I do not have enough blah...

The final thing to make it work is to pass a null value to your report... This can be done in different ways, but this is how I was using it...

`ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter(tb.ID, new string[] { null }));`

Hopefully this helps.